# Customize appsetings.json for user in ASP Core 1 app

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

My goal is to have `appsettings.json` file with production configurations and have possibility to costomize it for every developer, e.g. use local connection strings. So it does not similar to transform web.config mechanism, i don't want depends on bulid configuration. Can anyone provide solution for this goal?

In one of my past project we do so: we store all configure information in custom config.xml and parsed it into the custom structure. Web.config contains only server configaration. every developer has own copy of config files with his own data. Solution is that application use configuration files from path, that specified in environment path in windows via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")`.

Does anyone have idea better than my one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I manage configuration: see comments in the code

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"); // this one has default configuration

    // this file name is added to my gitignore so it won't get committed, 
    // I keep local dev configuration there
    builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.overrides.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // This reads the configuration keys from the secret store.
        // if you need a more secure place for dev configuration use usersecrets
        // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
        builder.AddUserSecrets();
    }
    // the order in which config sources is added is important, a source added later
    // will override the same settings from a source added before
    // environment variables is usually for production and therefore added last to give it higher priority
     builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
      Configuration = builder.Build();


    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i need. I have already found that solution with gitignore, but miss to answer y own question. Thank you.